# Gatsby: gatsby-source-graphql: Cannot read property 'createPageDependency' of undefined

Tags: gatsby

i'm build a Gatsby starter theme for fireblog ( https://fireblogcms.com/ ), which has a GraphQL API. So i tried `gatsby-source-graphql` plugin which seems the way to go :

When following instructions from this page : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/ and then visiting http://localhost:8000/___graphql , I got this issue `Cannot read property 'createPageDependency' of undefined`, when running a GraphQL Query on my new type.

To reproduce:

- `yarn add gatsby-source-graphql`
- add this config to `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
  plugins: [
    // Simple config, passing URL
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        // This type will contain remote schema Query type
        typeName: "fireblog",
        // This is field under which it's accessible
        fieldName: "fireblog",
        // Url to query from
        url: "https://api.fireblogcms.com/graphql/blog/5de7a2934360f60004130881"
      }
    },
  //...
  ],
```

go to `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`

and run query :

```
{
  fireblog {
    posts(last: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Expected result

I'm expecting query to run without error, or an error message to explain me what i should do next to make this query work.

#### Actual result

What happened :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'createPageDependency' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "fireblog"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

`gatsby info --clipboard` :

```
  System:
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4960HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.10 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 78.0.3904.108
    Firefox: 69.0.3
    Safari: 13.0.3
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.1.10 => 2.1.10
    gatsby-image: ^2.0.29 => 2.0.29
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^2.0.13 => 2.0.13
    gatsby-plugin-google-analytics: ^2.0.14 => 2.0.14
    gatsby-plugin-html2amp: ^0.4.0 => 0.4.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.0.18 => 2.0.18
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.0.24 => 2.0.24
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.0.6 => 3.0.6
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.0.21 => 2.0.21
    gatsby-plugin-typography: ^2.2.7 => 2.2.7
    gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files: ^2.0.9 => 2.0.9
    gatsby-remark-images: ^2.0.6 => 2.0.6
    gatsby-remark-prismjs: ^3.2.4 => 3.2.4
    gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe: ^2.0.9 => 2.0.9
    gatsby-remark-smartypants: ^2.0.8 => 2.0.8
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.0.20 => 2.0.20
    gatsby-source-graphql: ^2.1.28 => 2.1.28
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.2.5 => 2.2.5
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.1.14 => 2.1.14
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was my node version, it's okay with my last test on node 12.4.0. If i remember well, i was previously on node 10.13.0